# pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt

Tags: linux, python-3.x

sudo /usr/bin/pip3.6 install httpie -U                                Traceback

```
(most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3.6", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import plistlib
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/plistlib.py", line 65, in <module>
    from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyexpat import *
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt

ldd /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc1d185000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f0864d3d000)
        libpython3.6m.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 (0x00007f0864854000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0864637000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0864274000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0864070000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f0863e6c000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0863b6a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000560fba761000)
```

Any ideas why i am suddenly getting this problem ?

Comment: Could you please do let me know if you got any answer for this one please?

Comment: Nope I never got an answer to this question and ended up reinstalling the whole thing from scratch